# nlist function always returns -1

Tags: c, file, bsd

I made exe file (d.out) by compiling another program. And  nlist function always returns -1. fopen func returns !=null. If it matters i compile my prog like this 
`gcc -I/usr/include main.c -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkgconfig -lbsd`

```
#include <string.h>
#include <bsd/nlist.h>
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int test(){
    struct nlist nl[2];
    memset(&nl, 0, sizeof(nl));
    return  nlist("d.out", nl);
//  return nl[0].n_value;
}

int main(){


printf("%d \n", test());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My FreeBSD man page says:

> **RETURN VALUES**
>        The number of invalid entries is returned if successful; otherwise, if
>        the file filename does not exist or is not executable, the returned value
>        is -1.

Does `d.out` exist?

Comment: ofcourse it exists. I tried to fopen it and it returns !=NULL .

Comment: @ArseniyErmilov And of course the x bits aren't missing? And `file d.out` says it is an executable?

Comment: `d.out: ELF 32-bit  LSB executable ...`  `-rwxrwxrwx 1 username ... `

Comment: I run it gdb. And at some moment in func nlist gdb prints : `_dl_runtime_resolve () at ../sysdeps/i386/dl-trampoline.S:35 ../sysdeps/i386/dl-trampoline.S: No such file or catalog` . Maybe it doesnt work because of this ?